# Difficulties understanding how to take elements from a file and store them in C

Tags: arrays, c, file, scanf

I'm working on an assignment that is supposed to go over the basics of reading a file and storing the information from that file. I'm personally new to C and struggling with the lack of a "String" variable.

The file that the program is supposed to work with contains temperature values, but we are supposed to account for "corrupted data". The assignment states:

> Every input item read from the file should be treated as a stream of characters (string), you can
> use the function atof() to convert a string value into a floating point number (invalid data can be
> set to a value lower than the lowest minimum to identify it as corrupt)."

The number of elements in the file is undetermined but an example given is:

> 37.8, 38.a, 139.1, abc.5, 37.9, 38.8, 40.5, 39.0, 36.9, 39.8

After reading the file we're supposed to allow a user to query these individual entries, but as mentioned if the data entry contains a non-numeric value, we are supposed to state that the specific data entry is corrupted.

Overall, I understand how to functionally write a program that can fulfill those requirements. My issue is not knowing what data structure to use and/or how to store the information to be called upon later.

Comment: An array would work. `atof` returns 0.0 if it cannot convert. thus any 0.0 in the array would represent an error.

Comment: I think they are saying that you have to build each string yourself, character by character, identifying unexpected characters such as the `a` in `38.a`. An unknown amount of data can be stored with a linked list by a dynamic allocation of each node, or in a dynamically allocated array, which can be reallocated to a larger size when you run out of room.

Answer (score 0):

The closest to an actual string datatype which you find in C is a sequence of `char`s which is terminated by a `'\0'` value. That is used for most things which you'd expect to do with strings.

Storing them requires just sufficent memory, as offered by a sufficiently large array of `char`, or as offered by `malloc()`.

I think the requirements of your assignment would be met by making a char array as buffer, then reading in with `fgets()`, making sure to not read more than fits into your array and making sure that there is a `'\0'` at the end.

Then you can use `atof()` on the content of the array and if it fails do the handling of corrupted input. Though I would prefer `sscanf()` for its better feedback via separate return value.

Comment: We've been taught using fscanf(), is this a viable approach to do that? I was trying to sketch out how that would work but I didn't know the correct format approach to assign the variables. Such as if the information was just being printed, I could do something like:

            while(status = fscanf(dataFile, "%s", string1) != EOF) {
                printf("%s\n", string1); }

How would that be iterated to make said array?

Comment: For that question please create a new question post.